# setRetainDays in embedded jetty not working

Tags: embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using embedded jetty 9.2.22 and found that the http access logs are not getting deleted , even if i set the retaindays as 0 or 1. After setting 0 or 1 for the retaindays , i have changed the system time and started the jetty and found that the http access logs are not getting deleted.

```java
RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
NCSARequestLog requestLog = new NCSARequestLog();

String filename = System.getProperty("user.dir") "/logs/http-yyyy_mm_dd.log";
File file = new File(filename);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
requestLog.setFilename(filename);
requestLog.setAppend("true");
requestLog.setExtended("false");
requestLog.setLogCookies(false));
requestLog.setLogTimeZone("GMT");           
requestLog.setRetainDays(0);
requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
handlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
```

Comment: However, I could see that the log filenames converting to zip file and changing its name after jetty restart

Answer (score 1):

A `retainDays` of `0` effectively disables the entire `retainDays` logic and no files ever get deleted.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.9.v20180320/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/RolloverFileOutputStream.java#L333

The smallest legal value is `1`.

Alternate option is to use [`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Slf4jRequestLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.html) instead of `NCSARequestLog` and have your logging library of choice do the file rotation, archiving, and retain on any configuration of your choice.

Comment: But, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Slf4jRequestLog  doesn't seems to be having retainLogs ..

Comment: Exactly, it sends the log events to the slf4j implementation of your choice.  That implementation (be it logback, or log4j 1.x, or log4j 2.x, or java.util.logging, or commons-logging, or android, or nlog4j, etc...) will have all of the controls and knobs your chosen logging implementation.

Comment: Thanks...Do you have any examples for this ?

Comment: Actually, I'm using embedded jetty . So, i need to set the Slf4jRequestLog and then the handler before the jetty start up. Not sure whether i can pass the log events to log4j before jetty startup?

Comment: Read the slf4j documentation about how to pick the right jars to have events from slf4j be sent to to your log4j.  Note that there is no configuration on the slf4j side, the existence of certain jars (generally) dictate how slf4j operates.

Comment: Looks like, I can't access log4j jars before starting jetty. since , slf4jrequestlog is in jetty, i can access only slf4jrequestlog. But, my problem is to setRetainDays and i don't want to see the old http logs which ncsarequestlog not properly cleaning up. Can anyone have suggestion for this ?

Comment: It looks like this occurs when daylight time. Jdk is not working correctly , when DST is enabled..

Comment: Make sure you are using a recent version of Jetty, as the [DST issue was addressed back in Feb 2017](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1357).